# Cisco Netflow with nfdump

Tags: netflow

I've been using nfdump to read netflow data from my router but my problem is that the flow duration field is measured in milliseconds. I'd like for this to me measured in micro or nanoseconds if possible. Does anyone know anything about nfdump or netflow that they could help me to do this? I've already checked the ubuntu manpage and can't find anything about my problem there.

Thanks in advance, 
Shane

Answer (score 0):

NetFlow's precision is limited to milliseconds by spec. There are software netflow exporters that report nanosecond-precision, but they do so using a custom NetFlow 9 field.

Answer (score 0):

millisecond precision is highest precision in NetFlow v9 export. Moreover, considering the use case of netflow, i believe, the more granular precision than milli seconds is not needed.